# Laravel Eloquent self relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent, self-reference, self-referencing-table

I'm new in Laravel and have problem with self relations in eloquent. 
I have table `users` with fields `id` and `referrer`, where `referrer` is foreign key to table users (each user have one referrer which is also users). And table `invoice` has relation to users.

I want to get all invoices for user and for referrer.

In model I made relations:

```
   public function referrer()
   {
      return $this->hasOne('User', 'referrer');
   }

   public function referral()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo('User','id');
   }

   public function invoice()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('invoice', 'user_id');
   }
```

And query:

```
  $this->model->with(['invoice'])
         ->with(['referrer'=> function($q)
         {
             $q->with(['invoice']);
          }]);

 }]);
```

But this query returns me users and their invoices but do not return referrer just empty array key `referrer =>`

**Updated**

I change relations :

```
   public function referrer()
   {
      return $this->hasOne('User', 'referrer');
   }

   public function referral()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo('User','referrer');
   }

   public function invoice()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('invoice', 'user_id');
   }
```

And now dumping result I see referrer relation but when I trying to get  `$user->referrer` I got just referrer id instead of referrer object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function referrer()
{
     return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'referrer', 'id');
}

public function referral()
{
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User','id','referrer');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So finally I found solution.

**Relations:**

```
  public function referrerBelong()
   {
      return $this->belongsTone('User', 'referrer');
   }

   public function referral()
   {
      return $this->hasOne('User','referrer');
   }

   public function invoice()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('invoice', 'user_id');
   }
```

Relation should be like that, I change name to referrerBelong, because I have referrer column and it make conflicts and return referrer id instead of referrer object.

**Query:**

```
  $this->model->with(['invoice'])
         ->with(['referrerBelong'=> function($q)
         {
             $q->with(['invoice']);
          }]);

 }]);
```

And in controller you can get referrer object using `$user-referrerBelong` and `$user-referrer` to get referrer id.

Answer was here : http://laravel.io/forum/01-22-2015-eloquent-belongsto-not-returning-relationships